# Exercises on finding volumes of revolution using double integrals

Tags: reference-request

In which book I can find exercises on the calculation of volume of solids of revolution by evaluating double integrals?

Comment: Any book on multi-variable calculus.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE. Are you sure you are posting on the right site? There is nothing in your question making it clear that it is concerned with Mathematica software.